# How to remove blank option from select when ng-model is empty?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have a select dropdown with a refresh button and a plus button. When I click on the refresh button the model is set to null, but when I click on the plus button the dropdown is shown with empty option. So, I need to display the dropdown without empty option, where `ng-model` is null only.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 npd">
    <div ng-if="minAge==null">
        <select ng-options="minAge.val as minAge.txt for minAge in ddloptions" ng-model="minAge" ng-change="ageCheck()">
         </select>
        <p>Select <br><span>Minimum age</span></p>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="minAge!=null">
        <a ng-click="minAgeRmv()"><img src="images/prf-mprmv.png" /></a>
        <p>Minimum age <br><span>{{minAge}}</span></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you create a plunker

Comment: You have `<div ng-if="minAge==null">`. If you don't want to show the select when minAge == null, then change it to `<div ng-if="minAge!=null">`.

Comment: @Brian Actually In case I have two show two div with null and !=null,So here is my issues is when I make model value to null the dropdown is showing empty option

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to remove the empty option, you can put this empty option inside select `<option value="" style="display:none;">Select Age ...</option>`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. It will filter out anything that is null (*All values where minAge.txt is not null*).

```
<select ng-options="minAge.val as minAge.txt for minAge in ddloptions | filter:{minAge.txt:'!!'}"
        ng-model="minAge" ng-change="ageCheck()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to filter out any property with a null

```
ddloptions = ddloptions.filter(function(item) {
    return item.minAge !== null;
});
```

Either use it inside your controller when you refresh your data or put it inside an [Angular Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)